# When happens to the current during reversed biased?

Tags: electric-circuits

The main working function of a half wave rectifier is to convert AC current to DC. My problem is to understand during the negative cycle. 
[image]
The above picture is time versus current. We can see easily that discontinuous current is passing through the diode as we are not getting any current during reverse biased.

Therefore if we connect any electronic device, will that work properly due to the discontinuous current?

Comment: The device has to be designed to work with rectified but unfiltered DC, otherwise it might get damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For devices like battery chargers, motors and lamps the fluctuating voltage ([ripple voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_(electrical))) does not really matter but for a device like an audio amplifier the ripple voltage may well manifest itself as a [mains hum](http://mynoise.net/NoiseMachines/50HzHumNoiseGenerator.php).